# Deploy blank cordova app on my Lumia 950 XL

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-cordova, lumia

I can run my Blank Cordova apps on any windows simulator.

When I try to deploy on my device  Lumia 950XL,  I have this error message:

> Bootstrapper could not connect to the machine. Did try windows Phone (universal) platform and others Windows Options. Same Error message.

Comment: did you signed it before installing in on your phone?

Comment: I don't think. It's my first device deployment in my life with visual studio. Can you tell me the steps please ?

Comment: I don't know steps, you can google it. But yes to install app on windows or ios you need to sign them first. On android it's not needed since Android sdk has it's default key store by which it signs app each time we build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. My option for developer was not correctly setup. Used the 3rd option not the second.

[image]